# Ruby library like Hashie that can use lambdas as properties

Tags: ruby, hash, configuration

Is there a Ruby library that works like Hashie except it can take a lambda as a property and call it when that property is accessed?

For example, I'd like something like this:

```
# Lash = Lambda-able hash
lash = Lash.new(
  someProperty:      "Some value",
  someOtherProperty: ->{ Time.now }
)

lash.someProperty      # => "Some value"
lash.someOtherProperty # => 2013-01-25 16:36:45 -0500
lash.someOtherProperty # => 2013-01-25 16:36:46 -0500
```

Comment: It wouldn't have generality because it would make sense only when the proc's arity is zero.

Comment: Why does that not have generality?

Comment: When the value is a proc, you want it to be automatically evaluated (called), right? If it had an argument, then what provides the argument? The proc can't be called without arguments unless its arity is zero.

Comment: The implementation I provided below works with arguments. If your proc/lambda has arguments, you should call it with the arguments. Eg. `lash.somePropertyThatTakesArguments(someArgument)`.

Comment: Secondly, and more importantly, if you don't want arguments, don't give it a block that takes arguments.

Comment: If you define it that way, then it has generality, but you did not mention that in the question. Since it is your original specification, people will not understand without you fully specifying so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation:

```
class Lash < BasicObject
  def self.new hash
    ::Class.new do
      hash.each do |key, value|
        method_body = if value.respond_to? :call
                        ->(*args){ self.instance_exec(*args, &value) }
                      else
                        ->{ value }
                      end
        define_method(key, &method_body)
      end
    end.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something similar a few days ago and ended up using Hashie 2.0.0.beta which gives you extensions that you can use with your own subclasses of `Hash`:

```
require 'hashie'
require 'hashie/hash_extensions' 

class Lash < Hash
  include Hashie::Extensions::MethodAccess

  def [](key)
    val = super(key)
    if val.respond_to?(:call) and val.arity.zero?
      val.call
    else
      val
    end
  end
end
```

This lets you do things like:

```
l = Lash.new
#=> {}

l.foo = 123
#=> 123

l.bar = ->{ Time.now }
#=> #<Proc:0x007ffab3915f18@(irb):58 (lambda)>

l.baz = ->(x){ 10 * x }
#=> #<Proc:0x007ffab38fb4d8@(irb):59 (lambda)>

l.foo
#=> 123

l.bar
#=> 2013-01-26 15:36:50 +0100

l.baz
#=> #<Proc:0x007ffab38fb4d8@(irb):59 (lambda)>

l.baz[5]
#=> 50
```

Note: this only works in Hashie 2.0.0.beta which you can install via Bundler by adding this line to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'hashie', :git => 'git://github.com/intridea/hashie.git'
```

or, without Bundler, using the `specific_install` gem:

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l git://github.com/intridea/hashie.git
```